# Convert UTF-8 to ANSI using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, utf-8, ansi

I have a VBA Excel code which takes Japanese data from excel sheet compares it with Japanese data in text file and replaces Japanese words with English words. But I am supposed to be able to do this on UTF-8 text file. This code replaces all the Japanese words with weird characters. How do I save without any issue ?

```
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

For n = 1 To lngLastCell
Label5.Caption = n & "/" & lngLastCell
searchtext = MySearch(n)
valuetext = MyText(n)

eplcCount = 0
spltCount = 0

searchpart = Array(searchtext)
valuepart = Array(valuetext)

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf

Loop


Close iFileNum

sTemp = Replace(sTemp, searchtext, valuetext)

'iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTemp

Next n
```

Code works well with ANSI characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Open` function from VBA works on `ANSI` encoded files only and binary. If you wish to read/write an `utf-8` file, you'll have to find another way.

The `utf-8` encoding has a larger set of characters than `ANSI`, thus it's not always possible to convert from `utf-8` to `ANSI` without loss. That said, a `String` in Excel and VBA is stored as `utf-16` (VBA editor still use `ANSI`), so you only need to convert from `utf-8` to `utf-16`.

With `ADODB.Stream` :

```
Public Function ReadFile(path As String, Optional CharSet As String = "utf-8")
  Static obj As Object
  If obj Is Nothing Then Set obj = VBA.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  obj.CharSet = CharSet
  obj.Open
  obj.LoadFromFile path
  ReadFile = obj.ReadText()
  obj.Close
End Function

Public Sub WriteFile(path As String, text As String, Optional CharSet As String = "utf-8")
  Static obj As Object
  If obj Is Nothing Then Set obj = VBA.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  obj.CharSet = CharSet
  obj.Open
  obj.WriteText text
  obj.SaveToFile path
  obj.Close
End Sub
```